# SQL Oracle how to split text into rows and retain the deliminator but not duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, split, substr

I have a column value e.g. 'IC123456IC789123'.
The value is an aggregation from different systems, so could be in the form of numbers or letters/numbers with no fixed format e.g.
921253
X4525186
IC543534

Before the numbers can be used in another join, the data needs to be cleaned. The is a consistent pattern with one particular system that seems to combined two numbers e.g. the example with the IC prefix

I need to create two rows for this column, but only in this circumstance. the other data should be passed through and they should be distinct values (but in some cases, per the example, they are duplicated in a column)

```
results
'IC123456'
'IC789123'
```

But it should only create one row, if it is a duplicate

```
'IC123456IC123456'
'IC123456'
'IC123456'
results 
'IC123456'
```

I tried `REGEXP_SUBSTR('account','number','[^IC]',1,2) AS "PARTS"`

but only gives me the numbers without the 'IC' (which i need to retain).
Also, gives them on a new column, but i want to retain in the 'number column'
it should also return every other number which does not contain 'IC' in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string in 2 rows by IC keyword using Connect by clause and then use the distinct keyword to get the unique value -

```
select distinct 'IC' || trim(regexp_substr(value,'[^IC]+', 1, level) ) value
  from your_table
   connect by regexp_substr(value, '[^IC]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/KR2ISHOz)

Comment: If the table has input multiple rows then this is quickly becomes incredibly inefficient as each level of each row will be cross correlated with each other row at the same level when you generate the children and the next level and you will get exponentially increasing number of duplicate values generated which the SQL engine will need to store, compare and then discard. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rEbB9fr-)

Comment: i can confirm using a sample of 2 known errors that take less than a sec to load without correction, after 3 minutes with this approach, and it is still not giving results sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your values are all 8-characters long (`IC` then 6 digits) then you can use simple string functions (which are much faster than regular expressions) and a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (id, value, idx) AS (
  SELECT id, value, 1 FROM table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, value, idx + 1 FROM rsqfc WHERE idx + 1 <= LENGTH(value)/8
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       id,
       SUBSTR(value, 8*idx - 7, 8) AS value
FROM   rsqfc
```

If you have variable length terms (all starting with `IC`) then you can use:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (id, value, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         INSTR(value, 'IC', 1, 1),
         INSTR(value, 'IC', 1, 2)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         epos,
         INSTR(value, 'IC', epos + 2, 1)
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       id,
       CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(value, spos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, spos, epos - spos)
       END AS value
FROM   rsqfc
```

If you have variable length terms that take the form letters-then-digits then you can use regular expressions:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (id, value, term, epos) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '[A-Z]+\d+', 1, 1),
         REGEXP_INSTR(value, '[A-Z]+\d+', 1, 1, 1)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '[A-Z]+\d+', epos, 1),
         REGEXP_INSTR(value, '[A-Z]+\d+', epos, 1, 1)
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  epos < LENGTH(value)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       id,
       term AS value
FROM   rsqfc
```

Or, using simple string functions (which may be more to type but may be faster than regular expressions):

```sql
WITH patterns (id, value, pattern) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         TRANSLATE(
           value,
           'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
           'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0000000000'
         )
  FROM   table_name
),
rsqfc (id, value, pattern, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         pattern,
         INSTR(pattern, 'X'),
         INSTR(pattern, 'X', INSTR(pattern, '0'))
  FROM   patterns
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         pattern,
         epos,
         INSTR(pattern, 'X', INSTR(pattern, '0', epos))
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       id,
       CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(value, spos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, spos, epos - spos)
       END AS value
FROM   rsqfc
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, value) AS
SELECT 1, 'IC123456IC789123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'IC123456IC123456' FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | IC123456 |
| 2 | IC123456 |
| 1 | IC789123 |

*Note: `id = 2` is not duplicated.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ees-5UdL)

Comment: the length is not fixed, and not all values begin with IC. This is just an example where i need to do specific cleaning of the data

Comment: @GwaiTsi Updated with a third method using regular expressions that will match letters-the-digits.

Comment: i don't think this method works because a) there is no fixed format or length. b) the IC format and cleaning is only specific to a small number, but is important
https://dbfiddle.uk/0qEsG_gR

Comment: @GwaiTsi Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77127624/edit) your question with a detailed description of the problem (including the format of the data). If you do not tell us what the input data looks like and do not fully define the logic that you want to implement then we are left to guess at what the problem is. If you then come back and say "it does not work" then this is not constructive. **YOU** need to fully define the problem before trying to ask a question.

Comment: @GwaiTsi You have an XY-problem; do **NOT** split the data, just look for substring matches [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FelC8mk6). (And in future, do not store data in non-delimited strings; use delimited strings or, even better, store the data in a separate table in multiple rows and use a join to retrieve it).

Comment: @MTO data is not stored by choice. it is aggregated from different systems, and these exceptions are probably due to data errors, but have to be separated, because the number needs to be used in another join. so in your example it is a problem because IC2345 doesn't end up on a new row.

Comment: @GwaiTsi I refer you back to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127624/sql-oracle-how-to-split-text-into-rows-and-retain-the-deliminator-but-not-duplic/77127747?noredirect=1#comment135980052_77127747). You need to explain the logic properly in an edit to your question (not in comments on answers).

Comment: @MTO i did edit the original question